# Geometrical interpretation of solving a $3 \times 3$ system of equations

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, analytic-geometry, 3d

Solve the following system of equations and give a geometrical interpretation of the result.
\begin{align*}
x + y + z &= 6\\
2x + y − 3z &= -5\\
4x − 5y + z &= −3
\end{align*}

I know that each equation represents a plane in $3$-$D$
and that $x,y,z = 1,2,3.$ I want to show how i got that answer but I am have trouble formatting it. I used row reduction. But what do I do with that information. What is geometrical interpretation?

Comment: The solution represents the point of intersection between the three planes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the single point of concurrence between 3 planes.

If one variable is eliminated from the three, say $z$, then two lines intersect giving $x,y$ intersection.

Answer (score 0):

The catch is the fact that you are able to use **row reduction** to get an answer *just because* the system of three equations form a **consistent** system. In a geometrical sense, just because three lines (*each formed by the intersection of 2 planes*) are concurrent, you are able to get a valid solution (a point in 3D )by row reduction.(Gaussian Elimination I guess.)